# Pre-populating and compare select field with 'selected' option

Tags: php, html, forms

I am pulling form data from `home.php` into `results.php` and using `$_GET['xxxxx']` to pre-populate fields of another form. I can populate `input` fields okay, but how would you compare an `option` field and `$sale_type` to selected if equal?

**home.php**

```
<form action="results.php" method="GET">

    <input id="address" name="address" type="text" class="form-control1"/>

    <select type="text" name="sale_type" placeholder="Sale Type">
        <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
        <option value="Rent">To Rent</option>
    </select>

   <input name="submit" type="SUBMIT" value="Next" class="form-control1">

</form>
```

**results.php**

Option fields are already populated to ensure the form will work if it's used without results from `home.php`. I need to compare `$sale_type` value with the option of `name="sale_type` and if equal change that option value to selected.

```
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $sale_type = $_GET['sale_type']; ?>

    <form method="POST">

        <input id="address" name="address" type="text" value='<?php echo $address; ?>'>

        <select type="text" name="sale_type" placeholder="Sale Type">
            <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
            <option value="Rent">To Rent</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" id="filter">Search</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search">

    </form>
```

**What I'd like results to do**

```
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $sale_type = $_GET['sale_type']; ?> //If value is Sale

    <form method="POST">

        <input id="address" name="address" type="text" value='<?php echo $address; ?>'>

        <select type="text" name="sale_type" placeholder="Sale Type">
            <option value="Sale" selected>For Sale</option> //Change to selected if equal
            <option value="Rent">To Rent</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" id="filter">Search</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check and then marked as selected when condition satisfy. One of the example is :

```
 <option value="Sale"  <?php if(condition) echo "selected" ?> >For Sale</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd compare the variable to value in the option tag like so:

```
<option value="Sale" <?= ($sale_type === 'Sale') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>For Sale</option>
```

Another, *option*, if you will, is to set an array of sale_types. Instead of checking each individual option value, you could loop through the options and check there. Like this:

```
$sale_types = [
    'Sale' => 'For Sale', 
    'Rent' => 'To Rent',
    'SomeOtherType' => 'Something Else'
];
```

Then in select element:

```
<? foreach ($sale_types as $sale_value => $sale_option): ?>
<option value="<?= $sale_option; ?>" <?= ($sale_type === $sale_option) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?= $sale_value; ?></option>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to do very much of this at all, my recommendation is to build a PHP function.  Otherwise, you end up with a bunch of mixed HTML / PHP to check conditions.

This allows you to set up and display a dropdown quickly any time you need to.

Something like this would do what you want and would be re-usable:

```
// Function to generate the HTML for a select
function dropdown_array( $name, $value, $array, $placeholder = '' ) {
    $temp_input = '<select name="' . $name . '"';
    $temp_input .= ( $placeholder ) ? ' placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"' : '';
    $temp_input .= '>' . PHP_EOL;

    if ( is_array( $array ) ) {
        foreach ( $array as $val => $text ) {
            $temp_input .= '<option value="' . $val . '"';
            if ( $value === $val ) {
                $temp_input .= ' selected';
            }
            $temp_input .= '>' . $text . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    $temp_input .= '</select>' . PHP_EOL;

    return $temp_input;
}
```

Then, in your situation, usage would look like so:

```
$array = array( 'Sale' => 'For Sale', 'Rent' => 'To Rent' );
echo dropdown_array( 'sale_type', $sale_type, $array, 'Sale Type' );
```